# Revision history shows modification but not accurate by line

Tags: discussion, bug, editor, revision-history

I just edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31659208/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-in-codeigniter-and-show-the-output-parameter), and go to [Revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31659208/revisions) to see what my changes are look like.

I edit question to remove some noise text and removed this first line from question and some more stuff from bottom. I never modified the content from second line.

> Hi everyone I have a problem and I need help.

When I see revision history, its give me impression that I removed "`I have`" from second line while that's not the story.

So this is some kind of editor bug or something where it display changes but not accurately.

[image]

Comment: That's by design. Its not a full blown diff checker.

Answer (score 2):

That's neither a bug, nor is it inaccurate.  It's completely equivalent as far as the diff algorithm is concerned to say that the first "I have" is kept and the second is removed, versus the first being removed and the second kept.  They're *indistinguishable from each other*.

It's just comparing the text of one revision and another; it can't tell where your cursor was and which of the two snippets you removed.

Comment: exactly what I thought.

Comment: Sure it's equivalent and not a bug. It's *unfortunate* though, and should be avoided.

Comment: @Deduplicator:- how can we avoid that?

Comment: That's one for the SE devs, if they find the time to look and fiddle.